# Possible to make an "alias" or "macro" to call a JavaScript function in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, function, macros, alias

I'm writing a notebook in HTML for my own personal use. When writing an HTML document, you can't simply indent paragraphs with tabs or spaces. Rather than having to copy-and-paste several `&nbsp;` entities every time I want to indent a paragraph, I thought I'd be clever and write a JavaScript function to print 4 spaces. Unfortunately, I'll still end up copying and pasting `<script>tab_function();</script>` every time I want to indent something, which in that case I might as well just paste the entities instead.

I'm wondering if there is a way to create a "macro" or alias (like #define in C++) to make this less of a burden. It would be nice if I could #define "TAB" to call this function, but alas I don't know if such a thing exists in HTML. Is this even possible?

Comment: So you are writing an html editor? Or a text editor written in html? This is not clear. Maybe you are just looking for the `<pre>` tag

Comment: Nay, not an editor. Think of it as a book or manual written in HTML for easy navigation. There are images, tables, inline-blocks, etc. Many, many paragraphs. <pre> might be an interesting solution (feel dumb for not knowing about it until now, but at least I learned something), though I am still curious if something like <script>someFunction();</script> could be "macroed" into something short and easy to insert right in the middle of an HTML's body, rather than typing all of that in every time..

Comment: While this might be a useful learnng exercise, you don't need JavaScript for this; there's a CSS [text-indent property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent) that controls first-line indentation   See https://jsfiddle.net/mbwbo3jz/ for an example.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply write a event listener into your html.

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 9){//9 = tab
         //add 4 spaces, textarea.value += "    "; perhaps?
         e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

About macros, you can even sorta write your own compiler in javascript(compile to javascript I mean by that), by simply parsing text, basically anywhere.